# Android Studio inserting android:theme in Manifest file

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio (trying it out to compare with Eclipse) so following a tutorial. I added an android:theme to my manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="be.wotcha.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Now I'm trying to get rid of the android:theme so I edit the file and delete it, but every time I run Build/Clean Project Studio puts the android:theme back into the Manifest file and generates an error. Is there a simple way to stop Studio overwriting my edit? I'm using Studio 1.0.2 latest build

Answer (score 0):

Well, if You dont set your theme, the Android will set the default one for You. So set another theme or leave it in peace. App need to have some theme. App.Compat.Light is apparently the default one.

**EDIT**: What error do You get?

Comment: Well I tried changing theme to 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" but it still changed it automatically back to AppCompat.Light then gave me Error:(19, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light').

Comment: did You add library appcompat to your project? EDIT: And I hope that You change android manifest which is in your root direcory, right? Not this one in /bin?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are changing the main `AndroidManifest.xml`file which is located under `yourProjectName/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`